# Checking the lyrics: Mike Blakely's _Makin' Good Time_

Tags: lyrics

I am listening Mike Blakely's *Makin' Good Time*

The following lyrics are generated automatically by youtube.
Could anyone help me check it? Thanks.

If I had it my way
I get off highway
I pull up in the driveway
Taking in my arms

But I got a job to do
I know that you're working to
Make a better life for you and me

(*) Making good time on the road
Making good time coming home
I know you're awake there
Seen it in my mind
Coming on home and I'm making good time

All I do is miss you
Never could resist you
I can't wait to kiss you
Look into your eyes

It's been a long hard drive
But it's gonna be alright
As I can see the hometown lights and view

(*)x3

Making good time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections highlighted below

**I'd** get off the highway
**And** pull up in the driveway

I know that you're working **too**